# Error in Excel with Time function within Match function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use the Match function to return the row of an indicated table that a certain time value is on. The time is in mm:ss format on the table, so I want users to input the desired time to match as text for their simplicity (with data validation to ensure its correct format), and then use the Time function within the Match function to convert the input to match the format of the table for comparison. However, when using the Time function, the Match function returns the incorrect row, one row number short of what it should be to be precise. I attempted to do some debugging (shown below) and looked into the documentation of both the Time and Match functions, but can't figure out why this would happen. Is there something about the Time function I'm missing?

Here is a breakdown of what I'm using and what I've done to debug and figure out it's the Time function that's causing me issues. Column R has the functions I've been using and their results, and Column S has direct links to the table to show what the output should be. Column T shows that the time values are exactly the same but that using them yields different results in the Match function. Column U is the user input time in text format, and columns V through X are just used to ensure we get to the correct column in the lookup table.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ageCW.png)

Here is a snip of the table being referenced in the Match function.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgfGG.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is curious.  This is NOT a proper answer, but I needed to enter this as an answer rather than a comment because I needed the space and the markup of a table.  I created my own table and ran my own experiment.

I entered the time value of `00:01:23` three different ways:

1. I typed "00:01:23" into a cell manually.
2. I entered `=TIME(0,1,23)` in a cell
3. I typed "00:01:15" and "00:01:16" into two consecutive cells, and then dragged it down and let Excel autofill.

Here's the results I got:

| How Entered | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Typed "00:01:23" in Excel | 0.00096064814814814**8**0000 |
| =TIME(0,1,23) | 0.00096064814814814**8**0000 |
| Fill | 0.00096064814814814**9**0000 |

I emphasized the digit that turned out unexpectedly different.

I then did a MATCH(x,x,1) down this column for each value and it resulted in exactly the behavior you observed.  The first two matched 1:22, as they should, because they were ever so slightly less than the table value. The self-referencing MATCH() of the 1:23 cell correctly matched on 1:23.

What is puzzling to me is that my test revealed to me that the value in the lookup table was a tiny bit off, by (0.0000000000000000010000), where your test presented the exact same number, concealing the difference.  So in my test, the MATCH() behaved correctly for the data given, even if the data was wrong.

Excel is limited to 15 significant digits, and I have no way of knowing what rounding shenanigans Excel goes through to drop the remaining digits.

My thought goes to wondering how the time values in your lookup table were first created to begin with.  Like, were they initially entered in a google sheet and then opened in excel?  Is the 15 significant digit rounding handled identically among excel versions and OSes?

Comment: This was really helpful for my problem. I'm assuming there is some extra rounding nonsense happening after 15 significant figures, so I used the ROUND function out to 18 digits (since there are up to 3 leading zeros in my data), and it solved all my problems. Thanks!